# If prime $p=a_n10^n+a_{n-1}10^{n-1}+\ldots+a_110+a_0$ then $f(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_0$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

I have been trying to solve this problem on my own for four days now, and I cannot figure out how to prove it:

If we express a prime $p$ in base $10$ as
$$p= a_m10^m+a_{m-1}10^{m-1}+\ldots +a_110+a_0,$$
with $0\leq a_i \leq 9$ for all $i \in [m]$, then the polynomial 
$$f(x)= a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\ldots +a_1x+a_0$$
is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

First, note that $\gcd(a_n, \ldots, a_0)=1$, otherwise $p$ would not be prime.

I want to prove this by contradiction. Suppose, to the contrary, that $f(x)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then there exist $a(x), b(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, neither of which are units, such that $f(x)=a(x)b(x)$. Now $p=f(10)=a(10)b(10)$, which implies that $a(10)\in \{1, -1\}$ or $b(10)\in \{1, -1\}$ (whichever is the case will imply that the other is $\pm p$). Without loss of generality, suppose that $a(10)=1$.

Now, I was given the following hint: Show that $f(x)$ takes on infinitely many prime values, that is, show that show that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of integers such that $f(x_n)=q_n$, where $q_n$ is prime for each $n$. If I can show this, I am done because by the argument made above, without loss of generality, this would imply that $a(x)$ takes on the value 1 infinitely many times. Then $a(x)-1=0$ for infinitely many $x$-values, but since a polynomial has infinitely many zeros if and only if it is the zero function itself, this would imply that $a(x)=1$ for all integers $x$, a contradiction.

Can someone help me figure out why the hint is true? Thank you!! This problem is very interesting, don't you agree?

Comment: This is called the Cohn's criteria, if I am not wrong. One way to do this question, similarly, would be to bound the modulus of the largest possible real root of the above equation, and then use prime values of the function to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: See http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/Zagier/Solution3.1.html.